# Two way binding communication from two children component in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, components, blazor, two-way-binding

I've encounter some issues with two way binding in my app at work with Blazor WASM.
I'm trying to communicate a value between two child component who have the same parent component.

When I call a function to update my property like :

```
public async Task MyFunction()
{
    FirstChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(FirstChildInput);
}
```

it work perfectly.

But when i'm trying to put this into a property set like :

```
private string _firstChildInput;

[Parameter]
public string FirstChildInput
{
    get { return _firstChildInput; }
    set { _firstChildInput = value;
        FirstChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}

[Parameter] public EventCallback<string> FirstChildInputChanged { get; set; }
```

Nothing will work. When I start typing in my input my app start to freeze like if it's awaiting a response.

**-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is my code :

**Parent Component**

```
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Component Page</PageTitle>


<div>
    <br : />
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center; font-weight: bold;"><h1>Vous vous trouvez dans le composant Parent</h1></div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-evenly">
        <FirstChildComponent  @bind-FirstChildInput="_valueToPass"/>
        <SecondChildComponent @bind-SecondChildInput="_valueToPass" />
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    private string _valueToPass { get; set; }
}
```

**First Child Component**

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; height: 200px; width: 400px; border: solid 1px black; padding:16px">
    <h3>FirstChildComponent</h3>
    <br />

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
        <input style="height: 32px;" @bind-value="@FirstChildInput" @bind-value:event="oninput" />
        <br/>
        <span>
            <label>Résultat : @_firstChildInput</label>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    private string _firstChildInput;

    [Parameter]
    public string FirstChildInput
    {
        get { return _firstChildInput; }
        set { _firstChildInput = value;
            FirstChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> FirstChildInputChanged { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Child Component**

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; height: 200px; width: 400px; border: solid 1px black; padding:16px">
    <h3>SecondChildComponent</h3>
    <br />

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
        <input style="height: 32px;" @bind-value="@SecondChildInput" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>
        <br/>
        <span>
            <label>Résultat : @_secondChildInput</label>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>

@code {
    private string _secondChildInput;

    [Parameter]
    public string SecondChildInput
    {
        get { return _secondChildInput; }
        set { _secondChildInput = value;
            SecondChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> SecondChildInputChanged { get; set; }
}
```

I really don't know where is the problem. :/

I tried changing the EventCallBack by Action but it's seem's to not ascend the change to the parent when value is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is causing an infinite loop because the child and parent components are notifying each other forever that the value has changed. Check this related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599).

You can add check if new value is different from previous value to stop the infinite loop:

```
[Parameter]
public string SecondChildInput
{
    get { return _secondChildInput; }
    set 
    { 
        if (_secondChildInput != value)
        {
            _secondChildInput = value;
            SecondChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
}
```

But as [Steve Sanderson mentions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697588562) in the issue I mentioned above, a component should not set its own parameters. So instead I recommend this approach:

`FirstChildComponent.razor`:

```
<input value="@FirstChildInput" @oninput="OnInputChanged" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string FirstChildInput { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> FirstChildInputChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task OnInputChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = e?.Value?.ToString();
        await FirstChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }
}
```

and similarly `SecondChildComponent.razor`

[Demo](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/9vfovj5r)

Comment: oww thank you, it's working. I had seen this "if" statement somewhere but I hadn't tried it because I was thinking this was irrelevent.
BTW you said that a component should not set it's own parameters but in your example the component set his own parameter with a function. Doesn't that mean the same thing?

Comment: In my example the child component does not set the `FirstChildInput` property. When the input changes it simply invokes the `FirstChildInputChanged` event callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the new Net7.0 binding directives:

```cs
<input style="height: 32px;" @bind:get=this.FirstChildInput @bind:set=this.OnInputChanged @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
    //...

    private void OnInputChanged(string? value)
         => this.FirstChildInputChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```